How to get Google SSO provider_refresh_token
Using web login I get provider_refresh_token and can access Google auth info from Supabase.instance.client.auth.
await Supabase.instance.client.auth.signInWithOAuth(
  OAuthProvider.google,
  scopes:
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.readonly",
  queryParams: {
    "access_type": "offline",
    "prompt": "consent",
  },

Using mobile login, I don't get back any provider_refresh_token
final googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
final googleAuth = await googleUser!.authentication;
final accessToken = googleAuth.accessToken;
final idToken = googleAuth.idToken;

if (accessToken == null || idToken == null) {
  throw 'No Access Token or ID Token found.';
}

return Supabase.instance.client.auth.signInWithIdToken(
  provider: OAuthProvider.google,
  idToken: idToken!,
  accessToken: accessToken!,
);

I expected to be able to access the Google access token via Supabase.instance.client.auth, but it looks like it only contains Supabase info with some Google metadata. Am I expected to manually manage and handle the google Auth info outside of Supabase?
I am still struggling to find out how to get the provider_refresh_token on mobile. I have a long background process that lasts over an hour, and I want this to keep going even if the app closes (my back-end server receives the request from Flutter and does the Google call). I also don't want to do a check everywhere I send a request that checks where my Google access token is, whether from Supabase or custom logic of storing the Google token manually.
I actually have everything working using Keycloak, but I am migrating to Supabase to save costs. A lot of the code is dependent on the Google refresh_token being available.
TL;DR: I have login working on both mobile and web, I just can't seem to get the provider_refresh_token on mobile.
